# UNSUBSCRIBERS with different Subscriber Keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe, subscriber-key

I manage a central SFMC account which has 14 different Business Units, and we are dealing with a huge issue/problem, and so far we didn't have found a solution for it.
Each Business Unit welcomes and stores hundreds of leads in a daily basis, but what happens is one lead/contact can be converted in different Business Units, which means that one lead can be associate with different subscriber key.

Example: test@test.com converts on Business Unit A, and that same lead (test@test.com), goes to Business Unit B website and converts there... So we have one lead with at least 2 different subscriber key

Now, the scenario that we are trying to solve is: this lead wants to keep receiving communication from BU A, but not from BU B. It is possible from the central Business Unit, to establish some path where i can say which brand/Business Unit is allowed to send email marketing communication to a specific subscriber key or email/lead, instead of doing this in each Business Units?

Thank you in advance,

Pedro Nogueira,
Performance Manager

Comment: Have you looked at the Unsubscribe Settings at the BU level? But keep in mind, you can only control this from each BU separately, there is no solution for doing this from Parent https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_unsubscribe_settings.htm&language=en_US